# How can correct Ambiguous handler methods mapped?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I'm learning about Spring Boot and I have this code :

```
@GetMapping(value = "test/produits/{prixLimit}")
public List<Product> testeDeRequetes(@PathVariable int prixLimit) {
    return productDao.findByPrixGreaterThan(400);
}

@GetMapping(value = "test/produits/{recherche}")
public List<Product> testeDeRequetes(@PathVariable String recherche) {
    return productDao.findByNameLike("%"+recherche+"%");
}
```

The first method is searching with filter.
The second one is searching without filter.

Finally I have this error:

```
Ambiguous handler methods mapped for '/test/produits/300': {public java.util.List com.ecommerce.microcommerce.web.controller.ProductController.testeDeRequetes(int), public java.util.List com.ecommerce.microcommerce.web.controller.ProductController.testeDeRequetes(java.lang.String)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think fundamentally your API is ambiguous. The same verb + path would be confusing to me as a consumer.

It's also a bit limiting. For example, with your setup, you're precluding users from searching for "123" (perhaps it's product ID or SKU).

The `prixLimit` and `recherche` parameters seem to be filters/queries on a product resource, so it makes more sense to pass those as query parameters instead of the path:

```
@GetMapping(value = "test/produits/")
public List<Product> testeDeRequetes(@RequestParam(name = "prixLimit", required = false) Integer prixLimit,
                                     @RequestParam(name = "recherche", required = false) String recherche {
    // if prixLimit is not null
    //   return productDao.findByPrixGreaterThan(prixLimit);
    // else if recherche is not null
    //   return productDao.findByNameLike("%"+recherche+"%");
    // else
    //   return some meaningful default behavior such as all
    //   products, or return 400 to indicate a bad request
}
```

But there are a few options to disambiguate if using the path is a required part of this API:

**Add an extra Path Element**

```
@GetMapping(value = "test/produits/prixLimit/{prixLimit}")
public List<Product> testeDeRequetes(@PathVariable int prixLimit) {
    return productDao.findByPrixGreaterThan(prixLimit);
}

@GetMapping(value = "test/produits/recherche/{recherche}")
public List<Product> testeDeRequetes(@PathVariable String recherche) {
    return productDao.findByNameLike("%"+recherche+"%");
}
```

**Use Single Method to Handle Both**

```
@GetMapping(value = "test/produits/{param}")
public List<Product> testeDeRequetes(@PathVariable String param) {
    // if param is an int...
    //   return productDao.findByPrixGreaterThan(param);
    // else
    //   return productDao.findByNameLike("%"+param+"%");
}
```

**Use Regex in Path Mappings**

This is still a bit limiting because the two regex patterns must be mutually exclusive or you'll get the same duplicate mapping exception:

```
// This can only handle digits
@GetMapping(value = "test/produits/{prixLimit:[0-9]+}")
public List<Product> testeDeRequetes(@PathVariable int prixLimit) {
    return productDao.findByPrixGreaterThan(400);
}

// This can only handle characters
@GetMapping(value = "test/produits/{recherche:[A-Za-z]+}")
public List<Product> testeDeRequetes(@PathVariable String recherche) {
    return productDao.findByNameLike("%"+recherche+"%");
}
```

Note you cannot search for "abc123" in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use regex to make these methods distinct.

```
@GetMapping(value = "test/produits/{prixLimit:[\\d]+}")
public List<Product> testeDeRequetes(@PathVariable int prixLimit) {
    return productDao.findByPrixGreaterThan(400);
}

@GetMapping(value = "test/produits/{recherche:[A-z]}")
public List<Product> testeDeRequetes(@PathVariable String recherche) {
    return productDao.findByNameLike("%"+recherche+"%");
}
```

Here is the example (Section 4.3.@PathVariable with RegEx):

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping#3-pathvariable-with-regex

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use regex

```
  @GetMapping("/products/{id:[\\d]+}")
  public List<Product> (@PathVariable Long id){
  }

  @GetMapping("/products/{name:[a-zA-Z]+}")
  public List<Product> (@PathVariable String name){

  }
```